# Publishing a letter: how much extension can I ask for?

Tags: publications

I am attempting to publish a letter in a IEEE journal. The journal gave me 2 weeks to address the comments. It also mentioned that if I need more time, I should let them know as soon as possible so the editor can reset the dates. How much of an extension can I ask for?

I dont know how long its going to take to complete the revision, and frequently I find that I need more time that I originally think I would need. So instead of asking for extensions multiple times, can I just for say more that I think I would need at this point (say 2 months)?

Is that too much? First time publishing, so no idea of the protocols.

Comment: You can _ask for_ whatever extension you like, but you should _expect_ that the editor will say no.

Comment: For letter papers, and a minor revision (as you mentioned in your other question), I wouldn't expect the editor to extend beyond a week or so.

Comment: Is it possible that the comments from the reviewers could take more than 2 weeks? I don't think the editor might not have thought about it. I agree @MadJak, it can be max 1 week.